# How can apps like Autosleep get days of historical motion sensor data?

Tags: swift, watchos, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I want to replicate some of the functionalities of sleeptrakcing apps like AutoSleep. Apparently I can not open the app for a day or two, and when I open it up, it can accurately access the sensor data on my Apple Watch to see if I'm moving or not at any given 15 minute interval.

I've tried looking at various functionalities of CoreMotion. The closest I've seen is using `CMSensorRecorder` and call `recordAccelerometer` to start recording. However, this only allows you to record up to 12 hours. And the user would have to start the app to start recording. This is clearly a limitation that AutoSleep doesn't seem to have, because it seems to get the data out of thin air.

Anyone know how it's possible to get historical Accelerometer data from WatchOS that stretches back a long time without actively recording it?

Comment: Have you tried looking into HealthKit?

Comment: Yes. Nothing in HealthKit seems to provide data similar to the accelerometer